# Should a flywheel diode be installed for SSR with AC load and DC input?

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, circuit-protection, solid-state-relay, snubber

I have a solid state telay (SSR) that switches a 240 V AC appliances's input based on a 24 V DC input. The relay takes 24 V DC input and controls a 240 V AC connection.

I understand that for DC loads, it's important to use a flywheel diod in parallel to the load to protect the SSR from damage. In my case, the connected load of the SSR is an AC load (an inverter).

Do I still need to use a flywheel diode? If so, where should it be connected? Do I need to consider polarity for an AC load?

**Update 1**:
The load is an inverter which takes input of 240 V AC and a current of range between 10 to 20 A to charge lead-acid battery and to run home's electrical appliances. Here I am trying to use SSR to control the ON and OFF the inverter input which is connected to grid.

Comment: Please draw a schematic and indicate where the flywheel diode might be placed. Please link the data sheet for the inverter to see if it can handle a DC input.

Comment: @Andyaka The Inverter can not handle DC input. It only takes AC 240v AC and a Current of 10 to 20 ampere. amd for the Freewheel diode location, I am also not sure but I think it should be connected to the output of SSR. but based on Dwayne Reid's answer, I am not sure if that is a feasible aproch. Thank you.

Comment: You could increase information by linking the inverter's manual for example.

Comment: My Inverter Manual is available at:   https://5.imimg.com/data5/SELLER/Doc/2021/6/LI/TA/SJ/77574625/utl-gamma-plus-1kva-12-volt-mppt-solar-inverter-ups-pcu.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Because a standard diode is uni-polarity, it is not suitable for connecting across an AC load.

You can consider the use of a series resistor / capacitor as a snubber **OR** a bi-polar TVS with an appropriate voltage / power rating **OR** a MOV of an appropriate voltage / power rating.

We would need to know much more information about your load to give you suggestions of what you might want to use.

Comment: The load is an Inverter which takes input of AC 240v AC and a Current of 10 to 20 ampere to charge lead-acid battery and to run home's electrical appliances. Here I am trying to use SSR to control the ON and OFF the Inverter input.  Please ask me, what are the additional informations you would like me to provide.  Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like the load is NOT inductive.  In that case, you don't need to worry about inductive kick-back.

Comment: What you think about adding a heatsink is required or not? I am planning to use Fotek 100DA SSR but my maximum load conneced would be Never accessed 30A. In General the continuous load would be 20A or less and occasionally like on 10 hours in a week the load may be 30A.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike an electromechanical relay, an SSR does not require a freewheeling diode on the "coil" terminals.  The equivalent circuit of the input is either a diode and resistor, or a current-limiting circuit.  Either way, what's being driven is an IR LED shining on a receiver.  There is only the inductance of the connecting wires.

The output may need a snubber, or TVS or MOV, across the contacts, or load; how much, depends on the load characteristic.  In any case, this would not be called a "freewheel diode", as the direction cannot be predicted (it must work equally for both polarities) and there's nothing to clamp to.  Peaks can only be dissipated as heat.

The input characteristic of your inverter is not clear, but generally speaking, electronic devices have little inductance, and either smooth current draw (active PFC) or peaky current (plain rectifier input).  You can tell which case from the power factor listed in the spec sheet (if at all).  Either way, a zero-crossing type SSR is preferred, and in the latter case it should be rated for (and heatsinked to suit) say twice the RMS current, to account for the current peaks.  A snubber of say 0.1µF + 22Ω across the SSR "contacts" will probably suffice.

Zero-crossing type is preferred, to reduce peak inrush current.  Most equipment has inrush limiting so that it's only a small difference anyway.

Regarding the inverter, it's not obvious that the charger draws 10A at all.  The "10-15A" figure may interpreted as the output current.  It is a poor quality document, which reflects poorly on the equipment.  I would recommend a higher quality unit if possible.  It seems you will have to inspect or test it yourself to see what its actual load characteristics are.

Comment: I have added additional details of my AC load which will be connected to SSR output terminals. May you please answer a few doubts on your answer like Why zero-crossing type SSR is preferred? and what will be effect of Snubber circuit on connect power(any Voltage or Current drop or loss) when it is ON and OFF. Thanks

Comment: 10-15A is maximum ampere my inverter should draw as the maximum load it xan handle is 2kva which translate to 10 AC amperes but for margin i mentioned it between 10A to 20A.